# CodeIgniter Null result set from Mysql DB query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am updating an existing CI project on an AWS Ubuntu 12/PHP 4.2/CI 1.3.1 to a new AWS instance running Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS/Apache 2.4.18/PHP 7.0.8/MySQL 5.7.15/CI 3.1.0.

I can connect and select data from mysql command line using the settings in database.php  I wrote a non-CI test PHP page that also returns correct results.  The same query in the model returns 0 results.

I've been tweaking the settings trying to get this to work.  This is the current snapshot of **database.php**.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;
//  'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => '****',
    'password' => '****',
    'database' => '****',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => FALSE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

**Here is the applicable section of the model:**

```
class User_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        log_message("info","User_model class instantiated");
    }

... section omitted ...

    function login($username, $password)
    {
        $this->load->library('encrypt');
        // Get the hash of the entered password to lookup in the database
        //$password_hash = $this->encrypt->sha1($password);  (Removed 10/8/2016 ES SHA1 deprecated)

        $newpassword_hash = $this->encrypt->encode($password);

        $this->db->where('user_name', $username );
        $this->db->or_where('email', $username);

        $query = $this->db->get('users', 1);

        if($query->num_rows == 0){
            log_message("info","User not found");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
... remainder omitted ...
```

**var_dump($this->db->last_query());**

```
string(107) "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com' OR `email` = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com' LIMIT 1"
```

**var_dump($query);**

```
object(CI_DB_mysqli_result)#23 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> object(mysqli)#15 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(1) ["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 241ae00989d1995ffcbbf63d579943635faf9972 $" ["client_version"]=> int(50012) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(60) ["host_info"]=> string(20) "127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(23) "5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1" ["server_version"]=> int(50715) ["stat"]=> string(138) "Uptime: 229367 Threads: 7 Questions: 1083 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 440 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 241 Queries per second avg: 0.004" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(223) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) } ["result_id"]=> object(mysqli_result)#22 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(60) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) } ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> NULL ["row_data"]=> NULL }
```

Comment: Clarification - I have verified through var_dump the parameters are correct, the SQL statement is as expected.

I don't know what else to check to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use `$query = $this->db->get('users', 1);` this format to query in CI 
then the number of rows will be achieved by as following:

```
$this->db->where('user_name', $username );
$this->db->or_where('email', $username);
$query = $this->db->get('users')->result_array();

        if(count($query) == 0){
            log_message("info","User not found");
            return false;
        }
       else{
            //do what you want
        }
```

otherwise you can use like the following:

```
 $query = $this->db->query('your sql here');

            if($query->num_rows == 0){
                log_message("info","User not found");
                return false;
            }
            else{
               //do what you want
            }
```

Hope this may solve your problem.:)

Comment: I believe this is going to be a CI configuration issue.  The construct as written works on old server but does not return any rows in the result set of new server.

I did modify the code as per your suggestion to test but as expected, it still did not return any results.  No errors, no log entries, just no data.

Comment: I altered the code to use $this->db->get()->result_array() which seems to work.